# horizontal height is different between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, web

The page for Chrome and FF are very different, it seems like border in Chrome is inside the li, so the height is 130px, but in FF, the border is outside, so the height is 150px.

I have added more info for the code.

```
<div class="service_promos cf">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h2><a>item1</a></h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2><a>item2</a></h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here are css:

```
.service_promos {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.service_promos ul {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none !important;
}

.service_promos li {
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #e2e1d6;
    border-left: 10px solid #e2e1d6;
    border-right: 10px solid #e2e1d6;
    min-height: 130px;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 1em;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    display:block;
}

.service_promos h2 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 70%;
    color: #FF6526;   
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1em
}

.service_promos h2 a {
    color: #FF6526;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: it looks exactly the same to me see http://jsbin.com/aqiyep/1/edit what is the problem?

Comment: The height is different between Chrome and FF, FF is taller.

Comment: tested in both, but its the same. can you post screenshots?

Comment: It looks very fine in both the browsers. Dont worry.

Comment: What is your screen resolution . Check the zoom property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items that you provided appear to look just fine.

If you still aren't satisfied with their appearance, you may want to consider using either a **[Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)** or **[Reset.css](http://www.cssreset.com/)** reference within your Project / Page.

The purpose of these style-sheets is to help "normalize" all of the elements that are commonly used so that they appear similarly across different browsers and environments.

(*I would recommend checking if you have any other add-ins or extensions that could possibly be interfering with the appearance of any of your elements*)